# ASP.Net life of threads and spawned tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm new to ASP.net,

I am writing a webapi to kick off some heavy server side processing which I need assurance will complete.

At present the ASP.net request kicks off a new Task (Task.Factory.StartNew(...)) then returns a URL the user can poll to find status.

However I am getting the odd ThreadAborted exceptions in the serverside processing tasks and reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994085/are-there-any-non-obvious-dangers-in-using-threads-in-asp-net) I am thinking that using Task is not the best option.

Is there a better parallelism/async paradigm for spawning long running server side processes which need assurance of completion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS can recycle your application at any time so the web server is not the best thing to use for this. Your best bet would be to run a windows service on a separate server and either self host the WebApi in that or use MSMQ to send a message from the web server to the "app" server to initiate the processing.